# How does hashing algorithm convert hash to array index?

Tags: c#, arrays, hash, hashtable

I am trying to understand how can I create my own hash table.

If I understand how to implement hashtable, I would need something like this

```cs
public class HashBucket
{
   public object Key { get; set; }

   public ICollection<object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Then the hashtable would be like so

```cs
public class Hashtable
{
    private HashBucket[] _buckets = [12];


    public void Insert(object value)
    {
       // here I some how need to hash the value the insert it in the buckets array.

       var hash = getHash(value);

       _bucket[hash] = new Bucket(value); // here I’ll need to update or insert


    }

}
```

What I am struggling with is how to get a hash code to use as array index where I can retrieve the hash by index as well.

What is the algorithm of hash function to would create a value that would be a key of the buckets array?

Comment: Most if not all hash maps just clamp the hash value by using modulo. `where I can retrieve the hash by index as well.` You can't.

Comment: Sorry I still don’t understand how would I clamp the hash value using modulo?  I should be able to use the same value to directly locate the value directly using index.

Comment: `var index = hash % _buckets.Length`.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,327